# Updating Spinner using SQLite database

Tags: android

I need to constantly update my Spinner after adding data which it shows.
Part of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;  
Spinner spinner;  

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ArrayList<String> categories = databaseHelper.getAllCategories();
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In DatabaseHelper class, I make simple query which selects one column.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;  
Spinner spinner;
ArrayList<String> categories;  

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
categories = databaseHelper.getAllCategories();
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private function updateSpinner(){
    categories.clear();
    categories.addAll(databaseHelper.getAllCategories());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, bro! :)

Comment: Should you be calling that method? And `categories.add` could be replaced by `adapter.addAll` with the list as the parameter

Comment: @Mariachi u r welcome . consider @cricket_007 comment also. instead for loop you can replace with `adapter.addAll`. I will update the answer and dont forget to accept answer(tick symbol).